# Простой проводник с перебором для Windows

Tags: python-3.x

Здравствуйте. Как сделать перебор файлов в python? - И если найдёт строку, в которой будет написано Hello world! - то выполнится некая логика.

Я абсолютный новичок, но для меня очень важно решить эту задачу. Не знаю, с чего начать.

Весь код не прошу, хотя-бы кусочек, который наведёт на решение.

Comment: Алгоритм делится на две части: получение файла и поиск в нем строки. С первым справится метод os.walk, который будет возвращать список папок и файлов. С вторым метод open, который позволит открыть файл и прочитать его содержимое.

Comment: 1- Что значит "перебор файлов"? Вы хотите список файлов получить? По какому критерию? По расширению? Например, `pathlib.Path.cwd().rglob("*.txt")` находит все txt-файлы в текущем дереве директорий (рекурсивно). 2- что значит "найдёт строку"? Целиком строка? Или достаточно по подстроке совпадения? Что если несколько раз подстрока встречается в одной "\n"-строчке? В одном файле? Что вы хотите как аргумент для действия передать? 3- вопрос получения списка файлов и вопрос поиска внутри одного файла лучше (более полезно для других посетителей сайта) отдельно задать (для контекста можно ссылку дать